# Grails Spring Security Login Controller Testing

Tags: unit-testing, grails, spring-security

I have the following code in my login controller and I have to test if the user is logged in. How would I go about writing the test case?

```
def index() {
    if (springSecurityService.isLoggedIn()) {
        redirect uri: '/'
    }
    else {
        redirect action: 'auth', params: params
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this:

```
import grails.plugin.springsecurity.SpringSecurityService
import grails.test.mixin.TestFor
import spock.lang.Specification

@TestFor(YourController)
class YourControllerSpec extends Specification {

    def springSecurityService = Mock( SpringSecurityService )

    void setup() {
        controller.springSecurityService = springSecurityService
    }

    void "test index"() {
        when:
            controller.index()
        then:
            1 * springSecurityService.isLoggedIn() >> true
            response.redirectedUrl == '/'
        when:
            controller.response.reset()
            controller.index()
        then:
            1 * springSecurityService.isLoggedIn() >> false
            response.redirectedUrl == '/auth'
    }
}
```